# python regex to remove extra characters from papers' doi

Tags: regex, python-3.x

i am new to regex and i have a list of some papers' DOIs. some of the DOIs include some extra characters or strings. I want to remove all those extras. Here is the sample data:

```
10.1038/ncomms3230
10.1111/hojo.12033
blog/uninews     #ivalid 
article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0076852utm_source=feedburner&utm;_medium=feed&utm;_campaign=Feed%3A+plosone%2FPLoSONE+%28PLOS+ONE+Alerts%3A+New+Articles%29
#want to extract 10.1371/journal.pone.0076852
utm_source=feedburner&utm;_medium=feed&utm;_campaign=Feed%3A+plosone%2 #invalid
10.1002/dta.1578
enhanced/doi    #invalid
doi/pgen.1005204
doi:10.2135/cropsci2014.11.0791  # =want to remove "doi:"
10.1126/science.aab1052
gp/about-springer
10.1038/srep14556
10.1002/rcm.7274
10.1177/0959353515592899
```

now some of the entries don't have DOIs at all. I want to replace them with "".
Here is my regex expression that i came up with:

```
for doi in doi_lst:
   doi = re.sub(r"^[^10\.][^a-z0-9//\.]+", "", doi)
```

but it does nothing. i searched in many other stack overflow questions but couldn't get the one for my case. Kindly help me out here.

P.s. i am working with Python 3

Comment: What qualifies as characters you want to remove? What's your expected output for the input there?

Comment: following are some valid DOIs. they can include multiple . / and -
 ['10.1038/srep14556', '10.1002/rcm.7274', '10.1177/0959353515592899']

Comment: If you want to only keep items starting with `10.` you may use `[doi for doi in doi_lst if doi.startswith('10.')]`.

Comment: @TabKey add in question what is your desired output and on what basis

Comment: @CodeManiac eidted the question

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i want to extract the doi if it exists in the string

Comment: How can you describe the pattern to match a doi? Does it always start with `10.`? What does it end with or what chars or pattern can it have after the `10.`?

Comment: Please check [this demo](https://ideone.com/pXqYNo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the pattern for DOIs is a substring starting with `10.` and more digits, `/` and then 1+ word or `.` chars, you may convert the strings using `urlib.parse.unquote` first (to convert entities to literal strings) and then use `re.search` with [`\b10\.\d+/[\w.]+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/tR7suF/1/) pattern to extract each DOI from the list items:

```
import re, urllib.parse
doi_list=["10.1038/ncomms3230", "10.1111/hojo.12033", "blog/uninews", "article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0076852? ", "utm_source=feedburner&utm;_medium=feed&utm;_campaign=Feed%3A+plosone%2",
"10.1002/dta.1578", "enhanced/doi", "doi/pgen.1005204", "doi:10.2135/cropsci2014.11.0791", "10.1126/science.aab1052", "gp/about-springer", "10.1038/srep14556","10.1002/rcm.7274", "10.1177/0959353515592899"]
new_doi_list = []
for doi in doi_list:
    doi = urllib.parse.unquote(doi)
    m = re.search(r'\b10\.\d+/[\w.]+\b', doi)
    if m:
        new_doi_list.append(m.group())
        print(m.group())  # DEMO
```

Output:

```
10.1038/ncomms3230
10.1111/hojo.12033
10.1371/journal.pone.0076852
10.1002/dta.1578
10.2135/cropsci2014.11.0791
10.1126/science.aab1052
10.1038/srep14556
10.1002/rcm.7274
10.1177/0959353515592899
```

To include empty items upon no match add `else: new_doi_list.append("")` condition to the above code.

Comment: how to update the regex for doi like ['10.1038/s41593-018-0223-0']?

Comment: @TabKey Add `-` to the character class, `[\w.-]`.

Comment: Ok, just try `\b10\.\d+/\S+\b`, `\S` will match any non-whitespace char.